# move cursor to first or last line in current screen

Tags: notepad++

I need to create a macro or shortcut in Notepad++ to move the keyboard cursor to the first or last line of the current screen, by screen I mean the visible part of the document, for example, between lines 500 and 550, so, if cursor is on line 520, I want to jump to line 500 (top of screen) or line 550 (bottom of screen), the problem is, Notepad++ has zoom in/out, so sometimes there are more or less visible lines, with zoom-in the visible lines might be from 500 to 530, with zoom-out from 500 to 580. I know I can use the mouse but shortcuts were made for mouse-hating people like me.

Does anyone know how to create such a macro or shortcut?

Edit : in Visual Studio editor the shortcuts are Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn, but in Notepad++ those are used to switch between opened files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might come a little late as the question is a year and a half old now. Nevertheless, if you navigate to "Settings"->"Shortcut mapper..."->"Scintilla commands" you can assign hotkeys for "SCI_STUTTEREDPAGEUP" and "SCI_STUTTEREDPAGEDOWN" commands. These commands function very similar to Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDown in Visual Studio.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly (+1). Important : before I changed the shortcuts `Ctrl+PgUp` and `Ctrl+PgDn` Notepad++ said there was a conflict because they were in use already, so, I went to `Settings → Shortcutmapper → MAIN MENU` tab, found the shortcuts as `192 Next tab` and `193 Previous tab` and remove them, I went back to `Scintilla commands` and set the shortcuts without conflict. Nothing was lost because there are still two other shortcuts to jump to next and previous tabs : `Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`.